# How to save/load table contents using codename one and eclipse without sqlite database

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite, codenameone

I'm working on an application with [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) using Eclipse, and want to save the contents of my table to a file. Then load the content back when needed.

Is there a way to achieve this without using the sqlite?

I would like to avoid some of the complexities of working with SQL and the [Codename One documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) warns that sqlite isn't as portable and is more complex due to subtle differences between the iOS/Android implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Codename one storage to store some data, but do not use it in place of database. If your app requires database, don't hesitate on using it.

```
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Object Name", Object);
```

and use below to read after you've checked if it exists:

```
if (Storage.getInstance().exists()) {
    Storage.getInstance().readObject("Object Name");
}
```

You can also use Preferences if you are storing a small chunk of data and it's of known types (String, Long, Boolean, Integer, Double, and Float). I usually use this to save user session UserId and last time of accessing the app.

```
Preferences.set("Name", Object);
```

and use below to read:

```
Preferences.get("Name", defaultValueIfNameDoesntExist);
```